# jQuery Slider with restrictions

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using a jQuery Slider to let users pick how much money to pay to upgrade their server. I want the whole slider to be shown, but I want to slider to be restricted so that users can't slide the slider backwards past what they have already paid.

The slider itself works without the restrictions:

```
        $("#slider").slider({

        value: current_donation,
        min: 0,
        max: 120,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#price").val(t[ui.value]);
            $("#amount").val(p[ui.value]);
            var aaa = $("#price").val();
            $("#total").val(+aaa - current_donation); 
         });


    $("#price").val('$' + $("#slider").slider("value"));

    $("#price").val(current_donation);

    }
```

However, when I try to add a restriction

```
    $("#slider").slider({

        value: current_donation,
        min: 0,
        max: 120,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.value < 40) {
            return false;
          }
            $("#price").val(t[ui.value]);
            $("#amount").val(p[ui.value]);
            var aaa = $("#price").val();
            $("#total").val(+aaa - current_donation); 
         });


    $("#price").val('$' + $("#slider").slider("value"));

    $("#price").val(current_donation);

    }
```

The whole thing gets disabled and the slider doesn't even show up. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add this restriction by using slider api.

```
var min = $("#slider").slider( "option", "min" );

$("#slider").slider("option", "min", 40);
```

Comment: Doesn't that just start the slider at 40? I want the whole thing to be shown but not be able to move backwards

Comment: Right. Is this code exactly the same as the original one ? Because some paranthases seems to be incorrect. Do you get an error on console ?